# AngularJs - How can I filter through a nested array object in each iteration within ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following object in my controller.

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black', shade:'dark',variant:['metal','pure','knight']},
    {name:'white', shade:'light',variant:['pure','knight']},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark',variant:['metal','pure']},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark',variant:['metal','knight']},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light',variant:['chrome','silver','knight']}
  ];
}
```

Two questions.

1.How can I create a select box with 'variant' array in each object without duplication? Is this possible with ng-options? I'm looking for this -

```
   <select ng-model="selectedVariant">
    <option>Metal</option>
    <option>Pure</option>
    <option>Knight</option>
    <option>Chrome</option>
    <option>Solver</option>
   </select>
```

2. How can I apply filter to each variant array when using ng-repeat? I tried following

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <select ng-model="selectedVariant" ng-options="variant for variant in (c.variant for c in colors)"></select><br>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in colors | filter:{c.variant:selectedVariant}">{{c.name}}</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Will need a custom filter that use `selectedVariant` as predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can either write a specific function that returns only unique values of all `variants` merged together or calculate this value just once (as your list of colors seems to be static). You can easily transform from one to another. For example:

```
 $scope.allVariants = function(colors) {
    return colors.reduce(function(variants, color) {
      color.variant.forEach(function(variant) {
        if (variants.indexOf(variant) === -1) {
          variants.push(variant);
        }
      });
      return variants;
    }, []);
  }($scope.colors);
```

For the second, I'd go with a custom filter function. It's quite trivial:

```
$scope.hasSelectedVariant = function(color) {
    return color.variant.indexOf($scope.selectedVariant) !== -1;
};
```

Now this is how those can be used in the template:

```
<div>
   <select ng-model="selectedVariant" ng-options="variant for variant in allVariants"></select><br>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="c in colors | filter:hasSelectedVariant">{{c.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YfBPRd3jw811KXSLarNm?p=preview).